# Facebook - Are granted permissions cumulative?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

## Context

From [Facebook Best Pratices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist) I've understand that I should request a minimum set of permissions on the initial login page and delay the request of extended permissions for when they are really required.

For example. Say that my original login request for two extended profile properties:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"
     scope="user_photos, friends_photos">
</fb:login-button>
```

Now, at some latter point, the user wishes to upload a photo back their profile using my app (which requires `publish_actions`).

As I understand it my App have to:

1. Check if the user have already granted that permission (say, with `FB.api('/me/permissions')`) to avoid triggering a login flow for no reason
2. Ask for the new permission by means of performing a new login:

   ```
   FB.login(function(response) {
       // handle the response
   }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
   ```
3. Perform a second permission check to see if the user have granted the new permission. If the user have granted the new permission perform the upload, else display some kind of error message explaining to the user that he should grant the new permission before being able to upload.

## And my doubts are:

1. On the second step outlined above, should I ask only for `publish_actions` or should I also request already granted permissions?

   ```
   {scope: 'user_photos, friends_photos, publish_actions'});
   ```
2. I'm using a [Login on Client, API Calls from Server](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#authClientServer) model:
   [image: Login Model]

   So, at the moment that I request the new permission, my server will be holding a long-lived access token with the two initial permissions (`user_photos, friends_photos`). If the user grants `publish_actions`, am I supposed to go through the entire server side [token exchange](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) process again (using the new short lived access-token) before uploading?

   ```
   GET /oauth/access_token?  
       grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
       client_id={app-id}&
       client_secret={app-secret}&
       fb_exchange_token={new-short-lived-token}
   ```

   Or will the new permission be promptly available for the long-lived token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question to anyone facing the same problem.

**Yes, granted permissions are cumulative**.

1. > > Should I ask only for `publish_actions` or should I also request already granted permissions?

   I only need to ask for new permissions. Previously granted permissions remain available.
2. > > If the user grants `publish_actions` *(with `FB.login`)*, am I supposed to go through the entire server side token exchange process again (using the new short lived access-token) before uploading? Or will the new permission be promptly available for the long-lived token?

   The client side call to `FB.login` suffices. If the user grants `publish_actions` I can use the previously stored server side token to post content.

---

One small gotcha: When you call `FB.login` the user may skip the permission again (and it will return `response.status === "connected"`). So I had to actually double check for permissions:

Function to check permissions with *callbacks*:

```
function checkPermissions(perms, callback, failCallback) {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
        var fbPerms = response.data[0];
        var haveAllPermissions = true;
        if (typeof perms === 'string') {
            perms = [ perms ];
        }
        for (var i in perms) {
            if (fbPerms[perms[i]] == null) {
                haveAllPermissions = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (haveAllPermissions) {
            callback();
        } else {
            failCallback();
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming that `photoUpload` is a function that requires the `publish_actions` permission, here is the usage pattern that worked for me:

```
// First check 
checkPermissions("publish_actions",
    // If the required permissions have already been granted
    // call the desired method
    photoUpload,
    // else
    function () {
        // Asks for permission
        FB.login(function () {
            // double check - the usar may have skiped the permission again
            checkPermissions("publish_actions",
                // if the user granted the permission, call the desired method
                photoUpload,
                // else cancel everything and warn the user
                function () {
                    alert("Can't post without permissions");
                });
            }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
        });
```